# Does wrapping my Coalesce in a subquery make my query more efficient or does it do nothing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a query where one field can appear in either Table A or Table B but not both. So to retrieve it I use Coalesce.

Something like

```
Select
...
Coalesce(A.Number,B.Number) Number
...
From Table A
Left Join Table B on A.C= B.C
```

Now lets say I want to join another table to that Number field

should I just do

```
Join Table Z on Z.Z = Coalesce(A.Number,B.Number)
```

Or is it better to wrap my original table in a query and join on the definite result. So something like

```
Select * from (
Select
...
Coalesce(A.Number,B.Number) Number
...
From Table A
Left Join Table B on A.C= B.C
) T
left join Table Z on Z.Number= T.Number
```

Does this make a difference?

Comment: This would be better for you to setup some actual queries, run them, and then evaluate the execution plans. As posted this is so vague that about the only valid answer is "it depends".

Comment: `on Z.Z = Coalesce(A.Number,B.Number)` is going to be a performance hit though; as the query will be non-SARGable.

Comment: You could also LEFT JOIN Z on A and B in your first query with no coalesce.

Comment: I kinda doubt it matters. You might try rewriting as a union if this is a concern.

Comment: @RossBush but how can I just left join Z on A and B if I don't know if I am joining where the value is in A or it is in B. It will not be in both. That is why I am using Coalesce...

Comment: @nathan . . . You should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.  There may be way to get a performant query (i.e. one that uses indexes).  As written, this question is too broad.

Comment: As mentioned by @SeanLange, the answer might differ based on the size and structure of the underlying tables or how they are indexed.  In general, COALESCE is fast by itself.  I would also consider putting the join from A to B in a CTE and then joining to that. It probably won't make any difference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i were joining another table to the result of the first query instead of a sub query i would place the first part in a CTE whenever possible, i believe the performance would be the same as a subquery but CTEs are more readable in my opinion.

```
with cte1 as
(
Select
...
Coalesce(A.Number,B.Number) Number
...
From Table A
Left Join Table B 
on A.C= B.C
)
select *
from cte1 a
Join Table Z 
on Z.Z = a.number
```